# Locks used for purposes beyond atomicity

Tags: multithreading, locks

I'm reading articles about multithreading from a university and in one of those articles in order to show that Atomic and Lock()/Unlock() operations are different it says that 
"locks can be used for purposes beyond atomicity" but it doesn't explain any further. 
Can someone please give a couple of examples of the cases that locks are used for non atomicity purposes?

Thanks

Comment: READ: http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locks are used most often for mutual exclusion. You can use locks even if you don't work on shared memory at all. For example, you might want to call a webservice with at most one parallel call.